# WebClient problem - why doesn't the following code work?

Tags: c#-4.0

Why doesn't this code work?

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

webClient.DownloadFile(@"http://biblioteca.uqroo.mx/hemeroteca/tesol_quartely/1967_2002_fulltext/", "Vol_01_1.pdf");

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Vol_01_1.pdf");
Console.WriteLine("Worked!");
```

It starts to download but when I try to open the file it's corrupt and small in size.
Any advice?

DA

Answer (score 1):

You're downloading the *directory listing*. Follow your own link in a browser - it doesn't download a PDF, just a directory listing. Just put the filename in the URL as well:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

webClient.DownloadFile("http://biblioteca.uqroo.mx/hemeroteca/" + 
                       "tesol_quartely/1967_2002_fulltext/Vol_01_1.pdf",
                       "Vol_01_1.pdf");

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Vol_01_1.pdf");
Console.WriteLine("Worked!");
```

Answer (score 0):

Also use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadfileasync.aspx. The file takes time to download, so when executing

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Vol_01_1.pdf")
```

the file may not be downloaded yet.